# read javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have a JavaScript object of this form:

```
var myJsObject = 
{
    A.b: 1
    A.c: 2
}
```

How do I get the value of let's say `A.c`?

I tried:

```
var value = myJsObject['A.c']
```

But that gave me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'A.c' of undefined`

Thank you

Comment: You should post an actual example. The error you're showing doesn't match the error you should get given your example.

Comment: What you have here is not valid javascript as A.b cannot be a property name without at least putting quotes around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the "Object" keyword and should quote the properties. This worked in my console:

```
var myJsObject = { 'A.b': 1, 'A.c': 2 };
var value = myJsObject['A.c'];
console.log(value); // 2
```

Comment: I know, that was a typo, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Did you quote the 'A.b' and 'A.c' properties like in my example?

Comment: @gpojd - you are missing a comma betweenn your properties

Comment: Yeah, I think the comma and the quotes were the problems, now it works, thank you

Comment: @bPratik, that was a copy error from the original question. I fixed it when I tested in my console. I wouldn't have noticed...

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain dot notations. This should be working:

```
var myJsObject = {
    A: {
      b: 1,
      c: 2
    }
}
```

Or if you want to have a property name like `A.b`, it needs to be quoted, if the name contains special characters:

```
var myJsObject = 
{
    'A b': 1,
    'A.c': 2
}
```

Comment: yes you can't chain them, but OP using `myJsObject['A.c']` is still valid.

Comment: @bPratik Yes, I agree, but I was not sure, if OP wanted to create multiple properties for `A`, or just use properties named `A.b` and `A.c`.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
var myJsObject = 
{
    A.b: 1
}
```

produces a syntax error, because periods must be quoted, because they have special meaning in the language. The JavaScript interpreter read `A.b` as an attempt to get the `b` property from the `A` object, but it expects an identifier name, instead of an operation. Consider a similar example:

```
var myJsObject = 
{
    foo-bar: 1
}
```

Here, the hyphen is read a subtraction operator, and produces a syntax error also.

Instead, use a quoted property name:

```
var myJsObject = 
{
    "A.b": 1,
    "A.c": 2
}
```

(Also, your code is missing a comma after the `"A.b": 1` line which I added in as well.)